# Reduction in execution time when adding a counter

Tags: c++, optimization

I'm working on a program to find the number of moves needed to solve a rush hour type problem for a school project. ([Like this.](http://www.agame.com/game/rush_hour_2)) I've gotten it working, and am currently trying to get it to run faster. I've been timing my runs, and decided to add a counter to see how often many loops I was going through, and noticed my runtime fell by quite a bit. From an average of 2.5 seconds to an average of 0.1 seconds.

Here's the code for my main:

```
int main() {

board test;
map<string, bool> dejavu;
map<string, bool>::iterator it;
queue<board> q;
int runs=1;
test.loadBoard();

int abcd=0; //This is the line which changes runtime.

Timer t;
t.start();

while( test.numCars>0) {
    q.push(test);
    dejavu.insert(make_pair(test.data,0));
    int n=test.numCars;
    int m;
    bool done = test.solved( m );
    while( !q.empty() && !done ) {
        test = q.front();
        q.pop();
        for( int i=0; i<n && !done; i++ ) {
            if( test.moveVehicleForward(i)) {
                test.moves++;
                if( test.solved(m) ) {
                    done = true;
                }
                if( dejavu.end() == dejavu.find(test.data) ) {
                    q.push(test);
                    dejavu.insert(make_pair(test.data,0));
                }
                test.moveVehicleBack(i);
                test.moves--;
            }
            if( test.moveVehicleBack(i)) {
                test.moves++;
                if( test.solved(m) ) {
                    done = true;
                }
                if( dejavu.end() == dejavu.find(test.data) ) {
                    q.push(test);
                    dejavu.insert(make_pair(test.data,0));
                }
                test.moveVehicleForward(i);
                test.moves--;
            }
        }
    }
    q=queue<board>();
//  cout << "Scenario " << runs << " requires " << m << " moves" << endl;
    runs++;
    test.loadBoard();
}
    t.stop();
    cout << "Runtime: " << t.getElapsedTime() << endl;
return 0;
}
```

My class board uses no dynamic memory. The class consists of a "Board" 1D array mapped to act as a 2D array, the number of cars on the board, the number of moves which have been made, and the data about where each car is placed on the board.

For reference, run time with the line of code present

- Scenario 1 requires 93 moves
- Scenario 2 requires 3 moves
- Scenario 3 requires 10 moves
- Runtime: 0.161239

And the same test case with that line commented out

- Scenario 1 requires 93 moves
- Scenario 2 requires 3 moves
- Scenario 3 requires 10 moves
- Runtime: 2.64724

(The first test case is [this](http://quomodocumque.wordpress.com/2012/02/18/the-hardest-rush-hour-position/), with 2 simple cases following.)

Edit: No optimizations are used when compiling, however the runtime is identical when using -O3 optimization.

Comment: Please avoid i/o during timing your function

Comment: I spy, with my little eye, `map`s and `queue`s, both of which *do* use dynamic memory (at least with the default allocator, which is being used here).

Comment: Are you sure it's the line `int abcd = 0;` which is causing the difference? The rest of your code doesn't seem to be using `abcd`...

Comment: *"Edit: No optimizations are used when compiling, however the runtime is identical when using -O3 optimization."* You might as well delete the question.

Comment: @DieterLücking io has been commented out for testing.

Comment: @gha.st When I stated 'My board uses no dynamic memory' I was referring to the board class. Original is being edited so that is more clear.

Comment: @Daan I am fairly certain this is the issue. With the line removed, it runs in ~2.5 second, while if the line is present, it runs in ~.1 seconds. I asked this question with the hope that someone could explain where the difference comes from, as it doesn't make sense to me that there would even be a difference. The line isn't even within the timed section.

Comment: user3600511, what is your OS and compiler?

Comment: @osgx Running Fedora 19, compiling with GCC

Comment: user3600511, Can you publish your full code and binaries? What is output from `/usr/bin/time` and `perf stat` from both programs?